# ListPreference in Android Settings generating ClassCastException but i dont seem to find a point in code

Tags: java, android, xml, listpreference

The following is the code for the Preferences in pref_xml.xml file
this file defines the settings preferences for a weather app that takes in the location as edit text preference and units as list preference

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditTextPreference
    android:title="@string/pref_location_label"
    android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<ListPreference
    android:title="@string/pref_units_label"
    android:key="@string/pref_units_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_units_metric"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_units_values"
    android:entries="@array/pref_units_options"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The following is the code for arrays.xml file that defines pref_units_values and pref_units_options for options of units for the user

```
<resources>

<string-array name="pref_units_options">
    <item>@string/pref_units_label_metric</item>
    <item>@string/pref_units_label_imperial</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="pref_units_values">
    <item>@string/pref_units_metric</item>
    <item>@string/pref_units_imperial</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

The following is code defining all strings in the files

```
<resources>
 <!-- Label for the location preference [CHAR LIMIT=30] -->
    <string name="pref_location_label">Location</string>

    <!-- Key name for storing location in SharedPreferences [CHAR      LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="pref_location_key" translatable="false">location</string>

    <!-- Default postal code for location preference [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="pref_location_default" translatable="false">94043</string>
    <!-- Label for the temperature units preference [CHAR LIMIT=30] -->
    <string name="pref_units_label">Temperature Units</string>

    <!-- Label for metric option in temperature unit preference [CHAR LIMIT=25] -->
    <string name="pref_units_label_metric">Metric</string>

    <!-- Label for imperial option in temperature unit preference [CHAR LIMIT=25] -->
    <string name="pref_units_label_imperial">Imperial</string>

    <!-- Key name for temperature unit preference in SharedPreferences [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="pref_units_key" translatable="false">units</string>

    <!-- Value in SharedPreferences for metric temperature unit option [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="pref_units_metric" translatable="false">metric</string>

    <!-- Value in SharedPreferences for imperial temperature unit option [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="pref_units_imperial" translatable="false">imperial</string>
</resources>
```

And the next is the code for SettingsActivity.java file that links preferences from the pref_general.xml file.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
  implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
    // updated when the preference changes.
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
    //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key)));
}

/**
 * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
 * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
 * is changed.)
 */
private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
    String stringValue = value.toString();

    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
        // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    } else {
        // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

It is assumed that all classes and packages are imported. When running the above collection of files with other activities that perform the tasks of using the preference values to generate http requests to a weather database api, the app crashes when the settings button in the menu is clicked. Logcat entries show ClassCastException, with the below details.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.meet.mysunshine/com.meet.mysunshine.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                 at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:225)
                                                 at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1472)
                                                 at android.preference.ListPreference.onSetInitialValue(ListPreference.java:295)
                                                 at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1388)
                                                 at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1182)
                                                 at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:164)
                                                 at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:105)
                                                 at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:104)
                                                 at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:490)
                                                 at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:327)
                                                 at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:264)
                                                 at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:273)
                                                 at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1521)
                                                 at com.meet.mysunshine.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:38)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Pls. provide help finding the point generating exception. Thanks in advance.
And feel free to ask any other details about code.
Thank you!

Comment: I am suspecting this line: `onPreferenceChange(preference, 
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));` - please comment it out and see if the app still crashes.

Comment: Tried commenting the line you stated but its still the same.

I have noticed an unusual occurrence here. If I remove all the code involving the ListPreference from all files, the app works perfectly fine, with only the EditTextPreference. @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in the xml files. I've tried everything on java files. 
Note1: commenting the line involving " addPreferencesFromResource" resulted in proper working of the app,but the preferences do not show.
Note 2:the function calls to addPreferencesFromResource" and "findPreference" get deprecated due to some reason.is the whole problem because of this?